# Draw lines connecting centroids of objects using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have found out the centroid of multiple objects in my image using the code provided here [OpenCV examples](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html#explanation)

Here is the code which found the centroid and stored them in a vector.

```
cv::Mat InputImage;
    cv::Mat CannyOutput;
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    RNG rng(12345);
    InputImage = cv::imread("Untitled.jpg");

    //Edge detection
    Canny(InputImage, CannyOutput, 100, 150);

    //Contour detection
    cv::findContours(CannyOutput, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));

    //Finding Moments

    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
            {
                mu[i] = moments(contours[i], false);
            }

    //Calculating Centroid

    vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
            {
                mc[i] = Point2f(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);
            }

    // Drawing 
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(CannyOutput.size(), CV_8UC3);
        for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
            {
                Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
                //Drawing contour
                drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, cv::Point());
                //Drawing circles with centroid as centre
                circle(drawing, mc[i], 4, color, -1, 8, 0);
            }
```

What I want to do is draw a polygon with the centroid as the vertices. I used drawcontours, polyline and line functions but not getting the desired result. Is there a way to achieve this? . I need it to be achieved in C++

Output image

[image]

Desired image

[image]

Also, on another note, the code doesnt seem to be displaying the centroid if am replacing the 'color' variable with BGR value. Seems like both contour and centroid has to be of same color if i want to see the centroid. When i gave **(0,255,255)** for contour and **(255,255,0)** for centroid, the centroid was not displaying .

Comment: You already have centers stored in 'mc'. Now you need to try to find pairs that are adjacent and connect them. For two points to be adjacent, all other points should be on same side of the line passing from those two pints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given sample image, you can use [convexhull](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexhull) to obtain the order of centers, and then draw them with [polylines](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=poly#polylines).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Although, I had to convert vector<Point2f> to vector<Point>. I didn't have to use polylines. I drew contours based on the convex hull on my centroid vector.